# Include Sticky Posts in Page Post Count for custom query

Tags: wp-query, sticky-post

[This link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/180005/include-sticky-post-in-page-posts-count) solves the problem but it's only for the main query. What if you are using a custom query? How can you [modify the answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/76639/73579) below:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'ad_custom_query');
function ad_custom_query($query) {

    if ($query->is_main_query() && is_home()) { //how can we for specific custom query?

        // set the number of posts per page
        $posts_per_page = 12;
        // get sticky posts array
        $sticky_posts = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );

        // if we have any sticky posts and we are at the first page
        if (is_array($sticky_posts) && !$query->is_paged()) {

            // counnt the number of sticky posts
            $sticky_count = count($sticky_posts);

            // and if the number of sticky posts is less than
            // the number we want to set:
            if ($sticky_count < $posts_per_page) {
                $query->set('posts_per_page', $posts_per_page - $sticky_count);

            // if the number of sticky posts is greater than or equal
            // the number of pages we want to set:
            } else {
                $query->set('posts_per_page', 1);
            }

        // fallback in case we have no sticky posts
        // and we are not on the first page
        } else {
            $query->set('posts_per_page', $posts_per_page);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we can try the following: (***NOTE:*** This is untested but should in theory work, but remember, it is untested and can be buggy)

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'ad_custom_query');
function ad_custom_query($query) {
    // No other checks should be necessary
    if ( $query->get( 'custom_query' ) === 1 ) ) {
        // set the number of posts per page
        $posts_per_page = 12;
        // get sticky posts array
        $sticky_posts = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );

        // if we have any sticky posts and we are at the first page
        if (is_array($sticky_posts) && !$query->is_paged()) {

            // counnt the number of sticky posts
            $sticky_count = count($sticky_posts);

            // and if the number of sticky posts is less than
            // the number we want to set:
            if ($sticky_count < $posts_per_page) {
            $query->set('posts_per_page', $posts_per_page - $sticky_count);

            // if the number of sticky posts is greater than or equal
            // the number of pages we want to set:
            } else {
                $query->set('posts_per_page', 1);
            }

        // fallback in case we have no sticky posts
        // and we are not on the first page
        } else {
            $query->set('posts_per_page', $posts_per_page);
        }
    }
}
```

You can now just do run the following custom query

```
$args = [
    'custom_query' => 1, // Note, this has to be an integer, '1' will not work
    'paged' = > $paged
// I would just add all the other parameters in the pre_get_posts action
];
$q = new WP_Query( $args );
```

FEW NOTES:

- Because we will only target queries where the new `custom_query` parameter is set to `1`, we should not need the checks like `!is_admin()` or `is_main_query()`
- Because we are running a `pre_get_posts` action on our custom query, I would just set the `custom_query` and `paged` parameter in query arguments. Any other parameters I would simply just add in the `pre_get_posts` action.
- If you need to run a second query with different parameter and/or values, you can simply set `custom_query` to `2` and then just check in if the `$query->get( 'custom_query' )` has a value of `2`, like `if ( $query->get( 'custom_query' ) === 2 ) {`
- I have just copied your code and added the new parameter check, I have not worked through your code or changed anything

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a function I just edited the loop with the custom query. My example is for just one post to show.

I just used if statement if one or more sticky just show the first sticky.

```
<?php
$sticky_posts = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
$sticky_count = count($sticky_posts);

if($sticky_count >= 1) {
    $loop = new WP_Query('p=' . $sticky_posts[0]); //show only first sticky
} else {
    $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'category__not_in' => 'featured', 'posts_per_page' => 1 ) ); //if none show just the first non-sticky post
}

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?>
```